# ClassNotFoundException on a JUNIT ant script

Tags: ant, junit, selenium

I have written few test scripts using JUnit 4 and Selenium.
I have added the jar files for JUnit and Selenium to eclipse and if I run my tests through eclipse IDE everything is working as expected.

I am now trying to run these tests through the ant script below:

```
<project name="JUnit" default="test">

    <property name="src" value="./src" />
    <property name="classes" value="./classes" />
    <property name="test.class.name" value="AllTests" />

    <path id="test.classpath">
      <pathelement location="${classes}" />
      <pathelement location="C:/Program Files/eclipse 3.5/plugins/org.junit4_4.5.0.v20090824/junit.jar" />
      <pathelement location="C:/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.0b2.jar" />
      <pathelement location="C:/Program Files/eclipse 3.5/plugins/org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar" />
    </path>

    <target name="test">
      <junit fork="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
        <test name="${test.class.name}" />
        <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
        <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
      </junit>
    </target>

</project>
```

The problem is that when I run this ant script I am getting the following Exception:

```
[junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AllTests
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
```

I have added all the jar files that I see in eclipse .classpath file so a bit confused of which files I am missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem, stupid one but I guess it was lack of concentration...
My .class files are in the ./bin folder and the ant script was pointing to ./classes.
I copied it from an old ant script I've been using and didn't take notice of the properties configured.